# Clothing calculator using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a calculator for a clothing shop where the user can enter 3 prices, perform the total of these 3 prices, deduct a fidelity amount, deduct tax of 15% and display the total. What i am unable to do is to display a message which says Total is...

This is the code i've tried:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Bal(){
let w = document.getElementById('txtP1').value;
let x = document.getElementById('txtP2').value;
let y = document.getElementById('txtP3').value;
let z = document.getElementById('txtFid').value;
var Add = parseInt(w)+ parseInt(x)+ parseInt(y);
var Fid = Add-parseInt(z);
var Bal = Fid * 0.85;
document.getElementById('Bal').innerText = "Total is: " + Bal;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Body & Soul </h2>
<form>
Price 1: <input type="text" id="txtP1"><br>
Price 2: <input type="text" id="txtP2"><br>
Price 3: <input type="text" id="txtP3"><br>
Fidelity Amount: <input type="text" id="txtFid"><br>
<button onClick="Bal(txtP1.value,txtP2.value,txtP3.value,txtFid.value)">Total</button>
<div id='Bal'></div> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to display a message which says 'Total is..'

Comment: It works, you just have to stop the browser from submitting the form (the default type for a `<button>` is `submit`).

Comment: Or just remove the form element, I don't think it is even needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works but your form is submitting and you don't see the result. To prevent that from happening use [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the click event from the button.

I've amended your code slightly to separate out the inline JS from the HTML which might make it easier to follow.

```js
function bal(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let w = document.getElementById('txtP1').value;
  let x = document.getElementById('txtP2').value;
  let y = document.getElementById('txtP3').value;
  let z = document.getElementById('txtFid').value;
  var add = parseInt(w) + parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
  var fid = add - parseInt(z);
  var bal = fid * 0.85;
  document.getElementById('bal').innerText = "Total is: " + bal;
}

const submit = document.querySelector('button');
submit.addEventListener('click', bal, false);
```

```html
<h2>Body & Soul </h2>
<form>
  Price 1: <input type="text" id="txtP1"><br>
  Price 2: <input type="text" id="txtP2"><br>
  Price 3: <input type="text" id="txtP3"><br>
  Fidelity Amount: <input type="text" id="txtFid"><br>
  <button>Total</button>
  <div id="bal"></div>
</form>
```

#### Further documentation

- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) / [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Body & Soul </h2>
  <form onSubmit="Bal()">
    Price 1: <input type="text" id="txtP1"><br>
    Price 2: <input type="text" id="txtP2"><br>
    Price 3: <input type="text" id="txtP3"><br>
    Fidelity Amount: <input type="text" id="txtFid"><br>
    <button type="submit">Total</button>
    <div id='Bal'></div>
  </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Bal(){
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      let w = document.getElementById('txtP1').value;
      let x = document.getElementById('txtP2').value;
      let y = document.getElementById('txtP3').value;
      let z = document.getElementById('txtFid').value;
      var Add = parseInt(w)+ parseInt(x)+ parseInt(y);
      var Fid = Add-parseInt(z);
      var Bal = Fid * 0.85;
      document.getElementById('Bal').innerText = "Total is: " + Bal;
    }
</script>

</html>
```

In this example, you don't have to include arguments to your function because you already grab their values within the function.
Another option would be this:

```
<form>
  // Your code here
  <button type="click" onClick="Bal()">Get Bal</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should explain what you have changed instead of doing a code paste and expecting us to play spot the difference

Answer (score 1):

The browser will reload the page when you submit the form. To prevent that default action, use `event.preventDefault()` as follows.

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
Price 1: <input type="text" id="txtP1"><br>
Price 2: <input type="text" id="txtP2"><br>
Price 3: <input type="text" id="txtP3"><br>
Fidelity Amount: <input type="text" id="txtFid"><br>
<button onClick="Bal(txtP1.value,txtP2.value,txtP3.value,txtFid.value)">Total</button>
<div id='Bal'></div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code with the below code.

```js
function Bal(){
let w = document.getElementById('txtP1').value;
let x = document.getElementById('txtP2').value;
let y = document.getElementById('txtP3').value;
let z = document.getElementById('txtFid').value;
var Add = parseInt(w)+ parseInt(x)+ parseInt(y);
var Fid = Add-parseInt(z);
var Bal = Fid * 0.85;
document.getElementById('Bal').innerText = "Total is: " + Bal;
}
```

```css
#total{
 cursor : pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h2>Body & Soul </h2>
<form>
Price 1: <input type="text" id="txtP1"><br>
Price 2: <input type="text" id="txtP2"><br>
Price 3: <input type="text" id="txtP3"><br>
Fidelity Amount: <input type="text" id="txtFid"><br>
<p id="total" onClick="Bal(txtP1.value,txtP2.value,txtP3.value,txtFid.value)">Total</p>
<div id='Bal'></div> 
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, i did not understand exactly what you mean because i copied and pasted your code into an HTML document and that worked fine :) but i guess that your problem is refreshing the page after clicking the "Total" button. am i right? for this purpose add a 'type="button"' to your button attributes to fix that. Your code is right!